# What are some credible conferences and journals in computational neuroscience?

Tags: reference-request, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, artificial-intelligence

I have a background in computer science, and I wish to introduce cognitive sciences to myself, particularly from a computational/mathematical perspective. My motivation for doing this artificial general intelligence research at a later stage.

So far I only know of a few conferences that accept papers in the area of computational neuroscience & machine learning, namely [Cosyne](http://www.cosyne.org/c/index.php?title=Cosyne_17), [NIPS](https://nips.cc/), [ICML](https://2017.icml.cc/), and [ICLR](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/servlet/event.showcfp?eventid=56720) that accept papers in computational neuro. I guess that latter two (ICLR and ICML) accept papers which find some significance in ML. As for journals, I do not even know where to begin.

Comment: I think it matters a lot which discipline you are in. Here at my dept. we have a group doing auditory nerve modeling. They publish their stuff typically in Otology journals, because it's computational neurosci *applied to the auditory system*

Comment: @AliceD thanks, I think this question needs an edit. I am a CS major, and I want to induct myself in cognitive sciences, particularly from the perspective of computational neuroscience.

Comment: @AliceD thanks for the edit, surely looks better than how I phrased the question initially. I will practice phrasing my questions better next time. :)

Comment: There's currently no paper submission for COSYNE, just a 2-page abstract.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what was already mentioned, there are several "Frontiers" journals:

- [Frontiers in Neuroscience](http://journal.frontiersin.org/journal/neuroscience#)
- [Frontiers in Neural Circuits](http://journal.frontiersin.org/journal/neural-circuits#)
- [Frontiers in Computational Neuroscience](http://journal.frontiersin.org/journal/computational-neuroscience#)
- [Frontiers in Synaptic Neuroscience](http://journal.frontiersin.org/journal/synaptic-neuroscience#)

Then there are also several rather experimental journals that also sometimes publish computational papers, such as:

- [Elife](https://elifesciences.org/subjects/neuroscience)
- [The Journal of Neuroscience](http://www.jneurosci.org/)
- [Neuron](http://www.cell.com/neuron/home)
- [European Journal of Neuroscience](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1460-9568)
- [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org/content/by/section/Neuroscience) (proceedings of the National Acadamy of Sciences)
- [Cerebral Cortex](https://academic.oup.com/cercor)
- [Hippocampus](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1098-1063)

Another review journal would [Annual Review of Neuroscience](http://www.annualreviews.org/loi/neuro). I think [Nature Neuroscience](http://www.nature.com/neuro/index.html?foxtrotcallback=true) was also not mentioned yet but is very reputable. Some older (but classical) papers might even be in Physical Review Letters. Finally, there are many preprints to find on http://www.biorxiv.org/collection/neuroscience and https://arxiv.org/list/q-bio.NC/new.

I think it's worth mentioning that, as far as I know, conference papers are far less important in the field of Neuroscience than compared to Machine Learning.

Comment: What do you think about those Frontier journals? I think they are really iffy. Not to criticize your answer, I'm just wondering about your thoughts on them. +1

Comment: I understand the "iffy" feeling and one should mention that there have been controversies as mentioned e.g. in the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontiers_Media#Controversies). But my former supervisor has published there and I was also co-author on a paper and saw a proper peer-review process (well it's the first one I was ever part of so this judgment is not too valuable) which makes me think they're credible. Only anecdotal evidence but that's all I have.

Comment: @AliceD could you maybe elaborate a bit on why you feel they are iffy ? I would like to know if I'm missing/ignoring something about them

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on AI, but [Cognitive Sciences at Indiana University](http://www.cogs.indiana.edu/icogsci/pub.shtml) lists the following journals that cover your topic. The journals look credible, as they are published by Elsevier and MIT, both reputable publishers of peer-reviewed journals:

- **[Artificial Intelligence](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/artificial-intelligence/)** publishes state-of-the-art research reports and critical evaluations of applications, techniques and algorithms in artificial intelligence, cognitive science and related disciplines;
- **[Artificial Intelligence Review](http://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/10462)** is the reviews counterpart of above journal;
- **[Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research](http://www.jair.org/)** covers all areas of artificial intelligence;
- **[Machine Learning](https://link.springer.com/journal/10994)** covers research on computational approaches to learning;
- **[Neural Computation](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/toc/neco/0/0)** covers the scientific and engineering challenges of understanding the brain and building computers.

Answer (score 1):

You also will want to check out PLOS Computational Biology.

Most importantly, you want to read reviews in journals such as Nature Reviews Neuroscience, Trends in Cognitive Sciences, and Trends in Neurosciences, as well as the Current Opinion series such as [Current Opinion in Neurobiology](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/current-opinion-in-neurobiology/).